# How to implement Drag and Drop items between two lists in android?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am designing an application which requires Drag&Drop functionality to transfer items from one list to another.
Is there any way to drop item into another list, as i have seen applications to drag and drop items in the same list(Reordering the list)?

Comment: Have you got sol for it?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a direction to investigate than an answer: Have you tried listening to the button/touch down event in one list to get the item the use wants to drag, and then listening to the button/touch up event in the other list so that you know what index to insert the item at?

In the button/touch down event handler, the View object being touched is passed in.  In order to recover the original object that you used to create the View, you can attach it to that view via the setTag() function and recover it from the getTag() function within the event handler.

This wouldn't take care of any animation, but might achieve the desired functionality.